# $\{\,v, Tv, T^2v, \ldots\,\}$ spans $V$ if and only if $\{\,v, Tv, \ldots\,T^{n-1}v\}$ spans $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field, $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over $F$, $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation (ie. an $n\times n$ matrix). Let $v \in V$, how do I show that $\{\,v, Tv, T^2v, \ldots\,\}$ spans $V$ if and only if $\{\,v, Tv, \ldots\,T^{n-1}v\}$ spans $V$?

The backward direction is obvious, and for the forward direction I know that since $V$ is $n$ dimensional there is a size $n$ subset of $\{\,v, Tv, T^2v, \ldots\,\}$ that spans $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will have to prove that set $\{ v, Tv, T^2v \cdots T^{n-1}v\}$ is a linearly independent set. This will show that this set spans an $n$-dimensional vector subspace which must be the whole of $V$. We will argue by contradiction.

Suppose that the set is linearly dependent and hence there is a nontrivial relation among $v, Tv, T^2v \cdots T^{n-1}v$, then $T^{n-1}v$ lies in the span of the first $n-1$ vectors, now apply $T$ to this relation and conclude that $T^nv\in span\{Tv,T^2v, \cdots T^{n-1}v\} $. Keep going on in this way and conclude that every $T^kv\in span \{ v, Tv, T^2v \cdots T^{n-1}v\}$. But then the span of $\{ v, Tv, T^2v \cdots \}$ will have dimension less than $n$ which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Why do you say that $T^{n−1}v$ lies in the span of the first $n−1$ vectors? Could it not be the case that, say, $T^2v$ lies in the span of the other $n-1$ vectors?

Comment: @ihmth, yeah can be, I should have been careful. But that does not create any problem. See if for some $m\leq {n-1}$, $T^mv$ lies in the span of the other first $m-1$ vectors then you can apply $T$ to this relation and show that $T^{m+1}v$ lies i the span of the first $m-1$ vectors, and continuing in this way you can arrive at a contradiction.